# How can I upload a replay from Rocket League on Xbox to Discord?

Tags: xbox-one, rocket-league, discord

I have a clip from Xbox. I have tried posting it directly to discord, It didn’t work. Next I tried using Reddit and posting it from there. There were no subreddits to post it to like my other attempt, so that wasn’t going to work. On my other attempt, I decided to export it to r/rocketleague  then from there to discord. It actually worked, but this time there are no subreddits to export because none of them would allow my post to exist. After that I checked Reddit for a subreddit to post it to and there were none, I was lost and today, I thought of using YouTube or Vimeo as an export and then sending to discord from there. Would that work or do I have to find another way? If I have find another way, what would be it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a video file, just upload it to streamable.com and from there you can share it with any platform.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload it to onedrive on your Xbox and then go on another device in your onedrive and download it from there.

Answer (score -2):

I think if you get the Xbox app on your computer, you could upload it from there

Comment: why did this guy get so many downvotes?!  His answer was totally fine, and he's a new user for crying out loud.  I get it if you don't want to use an app, but that's no reason to downvote it.

Comment: didn't realize how old this question is, but my comment still stands.  =)

Comment: @Millard I upvoted because I agree with you. Looks like I'm not the only one with issues with commenting on old stuff!